# How to remove a mystery character from column header in R?

Tags: r

I have a mystery character in my dataframe in R:

```
df <- structure(list(`ID21` = c("23", "44"),
ID22 = c("53", "23"), `Drug-na�ve_D22` = c("53",
"45")), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame")

> df
  ID21 ID22 Drug-na�ve_D22
1   23   53             53
2   44   23             45
```

What's the best way to remove this character?  Would some sort of gsub with regular expression work?
In this example I've replaced it with the letter `i`:

```
> df
  ID21 ID22 Drug-naive_D22
1   23   53             53
2   44   23             45
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match any non-ASCII character you can use this pattern:

```
[^ -~]
```

So, for example, if you want to replace the char by `i`, you can use `sub` thus:

```
sub("[^ -~]", "i", names(df))
```

Answer (score 2):

To remove any non-word characters (letters, numbers and underscore) in your column names

```
names(df) <- gsub("\\W", "", names(df))
```

If you want to replace the characters with a different character, put them in the second argument